# Should my modem be connect to a LAN port on my router

Tags: lan

So the modem (a HT2000) has an IP address associated with it by default (192.168.0.1) it has a basic health page there for the modem. This can only be reached when connected directly to the modem not via the router (a DIR-822). This is of course since the Ethernet cord from the modem is in the WAN port of the router. Now the page is accessible if the Ethernet cord is moved from the WAN port to a LAN port but there is no connection to the internet doing so. How would I fix this so that the modems page is accessible and so is the internet? or is this even really a problem? as when the Ethernet cord is in the WAN port there is an internet connection.

[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7zYo.png)

Okay I'm really unsure about router settings as it worked by default the only thing I changed was the MTU value which is a recommendation by my ISP

[Internet settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nx25.png)

I'm not sure also this maybe of interest the router automatically sets 192.168.0.1 as the primary DNS server

[Home page where is says 192.168.0.1 is the primary DNS server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRihu.png)

Comment: Make a drawing of the situation. Now we have to disect your question to understand what is going on. Make it easy for us to understand your question!

Comment: If (and only if) the modem is actually a router, you can plug the modem into your routers wan, and just use your router as a switch, if you desire to do so. I wouldn't but I'm unwilling to expose my devices directly to ISP controlled hardware. If the modem is not a router however, you will need to plug it into the WAN of your router (such that you use it as a router; not just a switch).

Comment: This is probably related to conflicting IP address ranges on the WAN / LAN ports of your router... You've stated that the modem is `192.168.0.1` (presumably `/24`)... what is your LAN?

Comment: The IP address of the router is 192.168.0.2 and LAN address range is 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.199

Comment: I've added a basic drawing like I was asked I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a manual for the H2000 router, only for the [H2000W](http://www.montanasatellite.com/wp-content/uploads/hughesnet_ht2000w_satellite_modem_user_guide_1041264-0001_a.pdf).

According to this manual, the H2000W has a DHCP server, and can basically act as a router. If this is also the case for the H2000, then you can use your router as a simple switch, and connect the modem to one of the LAN ports. (Or configure your router so that the WAN port acts as a 5th LAN port).

If the H2000 can't act as DHCP server, and does have a fixed IP address or needs to receive an IP address from the router, then the modem needs to be connected to the WAN port, and the router needs to be configured to forward between WAN and LAN ports, so the status page can also be accessed from LAN. For details, both manuals (modem and router) are needed.

**Edit**

Guessing from the answers so far that you've configure your router to

- **Static IP** (page 25 in the manual)
- IP address = 192.168.0.2
- Subnet mask = 255.255.255.0
- Default gateway = 192.168.0.1

then go to the **Network** page (page 50 in the manual), and set

- LAN IP address = 192.168.1.1
- Subnet mask = 255.255.255.0
- DHCP IP range = 100 to 199 (exact range not important)

Connect modem to WAN port, PC to LAN port.

Then your PC should get an 192.168.1.* address, you should reach the router under 192.168.1.1, and the modem under 192.168.0.1.

If my guess is wrong, please explain configuration in the question.

**Edit**

Ok, your router was configured to receive an address via DHCP. Your modem WAN port gets assigned a [carrier grade NAT address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses), and the ISP nameserver is at `192.168.0.1`, which means your ISP uses this address range internally (though this is not the best choice, because many routers use it by default). So it **was** an address conflict, just between what your ISP uses and your LAN, and not the WAN and LAN segements in your home.

If you want, do a traceroute to `192.168.0.1`, and see what it goes through.

And **of course** the static setting is not working when in fact you need to receive a DHCP address. I was guessing, because you hadn't given this information (which you should have done in the first place), and asking you to describe your configuration, not prescribing something that was supposed to work.

Comment: The HT2000W is quite a bit different the manual (or I guess installation guide) for the HT2000 can be found here: https://fccid.io/ANATEL/00575-16-00871/Manual-HT2000/7BDBF2C8-7175-4D18-AE54-77E0B01527CD

Comment: Here is the manual from the router: ftp://ftp.dlink.ca/PRODUCTS/DIR-822/DIR-822_REVC_MANUAL_3.00_EN.PDF

Comment: The HT2000 is astonishingly unclear on the LAN settings, and the images of the status page etc. are so bad I can't make out anything. Can you edit your question with your router configuration that makes internet work in the WAN port? Did you just enter 192.168.0.1 as default gateway? If yes, change the LAN segment of the router to 192.168.1.*/24 (or whatever) and see if it works. Or do you need to enter an IP address you got during "commission"? (The more details you can explain in the question, the better - so far my understanding is much too vague).

Comment: Well it seems to be working now I left the internet connection setting alone (it didn't work with what you had said) and just changed the IP address of the router to 192.168.1.1 like you said and now it works. But why? it's not like 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 are conflicting IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Your modem should generally not be connected to your LAN port on your router.

There are situations when you do want to use your LAN port because you want to extend L2 functions without adding an L3 network. Occasionally I have done something like this when I don’t want to route but want to use the wireless functions on a cheap consumer router. In this setup, I recommend disabling the dhcp server on your router.

It sounds like your router LAN and your Modem LAN are using the same network (193.168.0.0/24).
If you change your LAN to a different network on the router, then it will forward traffic destined to the 192.168.0.0/24 network out your WAN port as expected. I recommend making your router LAN network in the 10.0.0.0/24 range, to reduce confusion in the future.

Note: The /24 notation in a network address indicates a network with addresses of X.X.X.(1-254) with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0

This doesn’t have anything to do with the specific model of your router but the difference between the way local network is handled vs traffic outside of the local subnet. Traffic destined to another network within my subnet goes directly to that neighbor. Traffic destined for an address outside my subnet goes to my default gateway (or more specific route).